# Opencart sms integration using php

Tags: php, sms, opencart

I have a page for registration of users where the user need to provide their name phonenumber etc for registration.
It accepts the phone number the following way.

```
 <input type="text" name="telephone" value="<?php echo $telephone; ?>"/>
```

phonenumber is storend in the db.

When the user checkout and goes to success.php, user should be notified by the sms

**This is a API form smsgatewaycenter**

```
<?php
$sendsms ="";
$param['To'] = "123456";
$param['Message'] = "Hello this is test message.";
$param['UserName'] = "my_username";
$param['Password'] = "mypwd";
$param['Mask'] = "TTNERD";
$param['v'] = "1.1";
$param['Type'] = "Individual";
foreach($param as $key=>$val)
{
$sendsms.= $key."=".urlencode($val);
$sendsms.= "&";
}
$sendsms = substr($sendsms, 0, strlen($sendsms)-1);
$url = "http://www.smsgatewaycenter.com/library/send_sms_2.php?".$sendsms;
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $curl_scraped_page;

?>
```

It works fine but

```
$param['To'] = "123456";
```

It sends the sms to the number 123456, i want it to send the sms to the number which is registered by the user during the registration process.
Should it be like this?

```
$param['To'] = '$telephone';
```

Please help.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit your success controller file.

Just go to `catalog/controller/checkout/success.php` and find `line no 5`.

You can see below code:

```
$this->cart->clear();
```

You need to put below code after above code:

```
$this->load->model('account/customer');                 
$customer_info = $this->model_account_customer->getCustomer($this->session->data['user_id']);
    $sendsms ="";
    $param['To'] = $customer_info['telephone'];
    $param['Message'] = "Hello this is test message.";
    $param['UserName'] = "my_username";
    $param['Password'] = "mypwd";
    $param['Mask'] = "TTNERD";
    $param['v'] = "1.1";
    $param['Type'] = "Individual";
    $sendsms = http_build_query($param);
    $url = "http://www.smsgatewaycenter.com/library/send_sms_2.php?".$sendsms;
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Now you can send your sms when user is `logged in` and complete `checkout` successfully.

Comment: Thankyou so much for this. But i want to implement this after checkout page. (i.e success.php) Can you please tell me how to do it. **sorry i didnt mention it before**

Comment: When the user successfully checkout from the store and reach the success page (success.php) after that i want the sms to be sent to the user.

Comment: u have missed closing parentheses `{
    $sendsms.= $key."=".urlencode($val);
    $sendsms.= "&";
 }`  Is that on purpose or it is meant to be that way?

Comment: Sorry, I have just miss closing parentheses because i have just copy paste your code.

Comment: sorry my mistake, i didnt see it.

Comment: Bro please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998835/opencart-sms-notification-to-users

Comment: Can you please put `print_r($customer_info);exit;` and check the result?

Comment: i inserted `print_r($customer_info);exit;` after  `curl_close($ch);` and the it shows this error  `<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: telephone in <b>/var/lib/openshift/54a93e5ce0b8cdda0f000031/app-root/runtime/repo/catalog/controller/checkout/success.php</b> on line <b>9</b>Array
(
)`  nothing else get loaded in the page.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help. i changed the code a little bit. `session->data['user_id']`  changed to `session->data['customer_id']`  and it worked. :) thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Getting data from form and configuration on event can be a difficult task. You can use any free sms module to send sms from your opencart store.

Example (a plugin developed by the company I work for): 
http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=27121

This module send sms on below events:

- Notify store-admin on new order and registration.

  - Send sms on new order place.
  - Send sms on order status change.
  - Send sms on account registration.

Events are configurable from admin area.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$param['To'] = $telephone;
```

if You earlier have sth like

```
$telephone = '123456789'
```

Comment: $telephone is declared in some other php page (register.php)
i want $param['To'] dynamically take the user phone number from the database and send the sms.

Comment: You can select if from database or get prom any other places ($_GET[], $_POST) but important is that these places could keep this telephone as a type of string, so You don't need your quotation marks http://take.ms/9gWrj

Comment: the telephone number is stored in the Database name: tatynerds   Table name: oc_customer  and Column Name:  telephone  Can you tell me how to select this table and column to place in $param['To']  fields

Comment: So You need to get it for example with SQL from DB. Sth like SELECT oc_customer.telephone FROM oc_customer WHERE any kind of condition here

Comment: but how to do it with php?

Comment: It's very broad question - You need to connect to your database, or use any kind of ORM. read more about http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_select_php.htm if You use mysql